# Gulp.watch will not keep watching files.

Tags: sass, gulp

I have the following code,

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6824071/

but when I run 'gulp' in cli it just runs the tasks and quits. It dosen't stay to watch the files and recompile.

```
Ezras-MacBook-Air:no1fitness-sandbox Ezra$ gulp
[gulp] Using file /www/no1fitness-sandbox/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to /www/no1fitness-sandbox
[gulp] Running 'default'...
gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch task triggering instead.
[gulp] Running 'styles'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' in 8.2 ms
[gulp] Finished 'styles' in 1.85 s
Ezras-MacBook-Air:no1fitness-sandbox Ezra$
```

The only way I can make it do it is by removing the task around the gulp.watch function.

is this right? Are there better ways (that work)?

Then theres the warning about gulp.run, which I'm confused about as their own docs still seem to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't calling the `watch` task — you are running the `default` task:

```
[gulp] Running 'default'...
```

Run `gulp watch` to run your watch task.

Comment: Yay that does work now.. which is lame as I've set that correctly several times before now and it didnt work then. :P any ideas on the "gulp.run() has been deprecated" issue?

Comment: Pretty much what they said — don't use `gulp.run`. Instead use dependencies, or — in this case — wrap your pipeline in a regular methods and call them from there, such as `function buildStyles() { return gulp.src(...).pipe(...)...; }`

Answer (score 3):

I know that the question was answered right, but this post comes from Google while I was searching for my problem and the solution in my case is:

```
npm install gulp-watch
```

Hope this saves someone else time ^^

Answer (score 2):

Another cause could be that the directory to watch does not contains any file. In that case 'gulp watch' stops immediately.

Comment: This was the issue for me. It was very confusing 